# Is Dr. Nefario supposed to be Gru's father?

Tags: despicable-me

I've seen this theory floating around and they usually cite:

1. Both having very similar noses
   [image: Dr. Nefario's pointy nose is also old-man droopy]
2. Dr. Nefario dancing with Marlena (Gru's mom).

However, is there any actual canon material (such as commentary or interview) hinting that Dr. Nefario is Gru's father?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, as you can see from the family tree that was posted on the official [Minionmadness](http://www.minionmadness.com) website, Felonius Gru (known to us as simply "Gru") is the son of [Robert](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Robert_Gru) and [Marlena](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Marlena_Gru) Gru.

[image]

Comment: Hang on, is one those ancestors a wolf?

Comment: @JamesSheridan - He certainly looks quite wolf-like

Comment: He may not actually have been a wolf. He may have been a werewolf transformed by an accident of science... Victorian Era science was notoriously unreliable...

Comment: Why not? Nefario who very well could be Robert, does resemble the "younger" Robert. I mean...look in the mirror 25-30 years from now...who is that old geezer, and more importantly, where did that younger you go?

Comment: @MartinH. The ears suggest that's unlikely, though it's possible he was so self-conscious that he had the artist make them regular-sized in the portrait.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist also your nose and ears never stop growing. that is why older people have large ears and noses.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Nefario was Gru's dad because in the second movie, Nefario says something like,  "Nothing can take away my 'Family,'" apparently.

Comment: Many people consider and treat their close friends as "family".